# find current directory level with PHP

Tags: php

I need to require_once a file that is located in my sites root directory. The problem I have is that I won't always know how many levels up the root directory is from where my current script is running. So I need to figure out how many directory levels I need to go up to require_once my file.

Some times it could be:

```
require_once '../../file.php';
```

And some times it could be:

```
require_once '../file.php';
```

Or any other number of directory levels up.

How can I calculate how many "../" I need to get to the root directory from any location in a sub directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a constant `SITE_ROOT` in your `index.php` and use it everywhere you need to specify the path, like:

```
require_once SITE_ROOT . '/path/from/siteroot/to/file.ext';
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple way that I figured out:

```
// get current file location
$pieces = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// subtract 1 for left / and 1 for current file
$loop = count($pieces) - 2;

// loop until to root directory
for ($i=0; $i<$loop; $i++) {
    $up_dirs .= "../";
}
```

Probably not as efficient as some of the other suggestions. But I tested it and it works.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!

Comment: i use this style in a function to have this usage through out. Works for all I need it to which is a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dirname(__FILE__)` to be sure that it's always the directory your include file lies

Comment: @zerkms: I didnt want to be striked with downvotes because "it was added in PHP 3..)"

Answer (score 1):

You can get the site's document root with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, and assuming that nothing in your code has changed the current working directory, you can retrieve that with `getcwd()`. With those two paths, then use the code in [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php#105876) to calculate the difference.

Comment: Even though this advice is often I cannot agree with it. Projects often contain a lot of files above docroot

Comment: @zerkms The OP did say "site's root directory." I interpret this as the document root.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: hehe, indeed subjective. I interpret this as "the application root" which doesn't equal to docroot :-S

Comment: @zerkms Agreed. I personally use your solution, but I thought this answer could fit the needs of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options. But you'll have to decide which is appropriate in your case:

- [`spl_autoload`](http://php.net/spl_autoload)
- [`set_include_path`](http://php.net/set_include_path)
- Relative path traversal with `include(dirname(__FILE__)."/file.php");`
- Server-root related paths with `include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/file.php");`

For applications a pre-defined root directory is the way to go. For libraries it's likewise the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the path from the top instead, for example

```
"/my/user/dir/file.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

`getcwd()` will return the current working directory string.